# how to search for a checkbox inside innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I want to sum a selected column inside a table. 2nd and 3rd column in my case. I managed to get the sum but I really want to add the value of a row in case a checkbox in column #1 is checked.

I can get the `innerHTML` value of a cell abut I do not know how to search or find out if the checkbox inside is checked or not.

`console.log(cell.innerHTML);`

returns for example

`"Extend      (2x)&lt;input type=\&quot;checkbox\&quot; id=\&quot;Extend2x\&quot; name=\&quot;Extend2x\&quot; class=\&quot;beru\&quot; &lt;=\&quot;\&quot; td=\&quot;\&quot;&gt;`

so I can see that the checkbox is there but that is where I ended up

I tried

```
console.log(cell.innerHTML.getElementsByTagName("checkbox"));
console.log(cell.innerHTML.html());
console.log(cell.html());
console.log($(cell).find(':checkbox').checked) returns undefined
```

but nothing worked.

Could somoone help me to find out? The working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/Lpxt3vu6/78/) You just click the checkbox and summing of the columns will be done.

Comment: `innerHTML` is text.  There are no method off of text, other than normal `String` methods.

Comment: `cell.getElementsByTagName('input')` would be the approach to try.

Comment: Or `$(cell).find(':checkbox')` for a jQuery approach.

Comment: The important thing to stress here is that `innerHTML` is a native Element property, not a jQuery property.  And `.html()` is a jQuery method, not a native Element method.  So you got all your stuff swapped around backwards and what not

Comment: Also noting that `input` is the tagName, not `checkbox`.  checkbox is the type value

Comment: @Taplar `console.log($(cell).find(':checkbox').checked)` did not work. It returned `undefined`

Comment: Because you are, again, confusing jQuery objects with native Elements.  jQuery does not expose native Element properties directly.  You have to either use `[0].checked` (to use the native Element) or `.prop('checked')` (to use the jQuery method)

Comment: @Taplar `$(cell).find(':checkbox').prop('checked')` works perfectly. Thank you. Do you want to create an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is this

```
$(':checked')
```

you can add stuff like input:checked, or something to make it more specific.

EDIT--
just saw the comments - and Taplar already answered this. Well this can be considered as alternative answer, and does not need to use cells / iterate through cells of the table.

Comment: so I can use `$(':checked')` instead of `$(cell).find(':checkbox').prop('checked');` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted. This is using jQuery for every reference to elements in the the dom (html).

```js
$(".beru").on('change', function() {
  updateTotals();
});

function updateTotals() {
  
  // loop cells with class 'celkem'
  $('.celkem').each(function(){
    
    // for each celkem, get the column
    const column = $(this).index();
    let total = 0;
    
    // loop trough all table rows, except the header and the row of totals
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr:not(:first, :last)').each(function(){
      if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
      
        // if the input is checked, add the numeric part to the total
        const str = $(this).find(`td:eq(${column})`).text().replace(/\D/g, "");
        if(str) {
          total += Number(str);
        }
      }
    });
    
    if(!total) {
      // if the total is zero, clear the cell
      $(this).text("");
    } else {
      // otherwise, print the total for this column in the cell
      $(this).text(total + " EUR");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Zinzino" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Název</strong></th>
<th class="sum"><strong>První balíček</strong></th>
<th class="sum"><strong>Měsíčně</strong></th>
<th> </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BalanceOil <input type="checkbox" id="BalanceOil" name="BalanceOil" class="beru"></td>
<td>149 EUR</td>
<td>30 EUR</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Extend (2x)<input type="checkbox" id="Extend2x" name="Extend2x" class="beru"</td>
<td>44 EUR</td>
<td>22 EUR</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zinobiotic (3x)<input type="checkbox" id="Zinobiotic" name="Zinobiotic" class="beru"</td>
<td>64 EUR</td>
<td>23 EUR</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Celkem</strong></td>
<td class="celkem"> </td>
<td class="celkem"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made it alread work using @Taplar's help. But your approach might be bit easier. I'll have a look. Thank you

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, I suggest you make this change. It will be much easier going forward. I also made small changes in the table, switching td with the class 'header' for th (the proper native way to do table headers), and I moved some css

Comment: You are right, I like your solution better. Nice code, more elegant. I do not fully undestand every single line of your code, I need to go through it more. Why did you use .closest?

Your answer is beyond my original question. I created new one so when someone searches for "sum columns" they would get grean answer. Could you please post your answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313608/how-to-sum-table-columns-using-javascrip-jquery

Comment: Great, thanks! I already left the same response .closest() is a jquery method that finds the nearest parent, in this case the nearest table element https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a reference to the DOM element then just select all the checkboxes using a selector.

```
var cbList = cell.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");

for(var i = 0; i < cbList.length; i++){

    //do something with each checkbox
    //cbList[i];

}
```

Remember a node list is not an array, so you can't use forEach ;)

Comment: Yes, NodeList is not an Array, but you can do `let cbList = Array.from(cell.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']"))` https://caniuse.com/#search=array.from